# Fit the text with label width java android

Tags: java, android

I need to show string "hello i am programmer and make app for android" in label and fit it with label width if string is bigger that label with

example show "hello i am programmer and make app..." if string is bigger than label width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:ellipsize="end"    //add this
            android:maxLines="1"       //add this
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:text="hello i am programmer and make app for android"
            android:textColor="@color/Black" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use this


android:ellipsize="end"  
   android:maxLines="1" 
   android:maxLength="25"
```